# Python thread pool consuming all my RAM and system hangs

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

i use thread pool for run 50 worker and my worker is a while true loop to crawl data from page , but my ram is gradually increasing and become full and the os kill all of my process .. can you help me what should i do ?
i tried  `from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor` and `from bounded_pool_executor import BoundedProcessPoolExecutor` but with both of them i had this problem.

```
with BoundedProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as worker:
        while True:
            worker.submit(createWorker)
```

and this is my creatWorker function :

```
    global index
    my_worker = Worker()
    workerIDs.append(index)
    index += 1
    if my_worker.redis_connection.length('feeder') >0 :
        message = my_worker.receiveFromRedis()
        my_worker.resolveMessage(message)
    my_worker.closingConnections(index)
```

Comment: How much ram do you have

Comment: @ShoaibWani 16 gig

Comment: is it necessary to use that many threads

Comment: for scraping may be you should use processes!

Comment: @ShoaibWani yes i want to crawl site , i need this worker to be run for ever .. but the ram is gradually increasing and become full